# Find the specific value from the query result set in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm getting cfquery result like below.This result set for one field value(single line).

Memberof = 
"CN=AG-880-ExpenseReports,CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com, CN=HTTP Users,CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com, CN=WA Houses,CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com, CN=MTViewMeadows,CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com, CN=**ALC0169**,CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com, CN=**ALC0069**,CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com"

have to take as a list of number ALC0169,ALC0069 from this also i need values only  0169,0069.. from that result set.

Is there a way of doing this with coldfusion?

Comment: Please verify that your criteria is that you want the part after ALC if the first 3 letters of CN are ALC.

Comment: this is a duplicate of [display string list in coldfusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772968/display-string-list-in-coldfusion)

Comment: @DanBracuk  - Yes i need after ALC numbers its 4 digit number only

Comment: @Matt Busche - good catch!

Comment: @TGR please close the duplicate question you asked earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772968/display-string-list-in-coldfusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very straightforward string processing script that will print out the list of numbers you are looking for based on your description.  Where I am printing out the numbers, you will want to capture those into an array or other structure depending on what you want to do with the data.

```
<cfscript>
memberOf = "CN=AG-880-ExpenseReports,CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com,CN=HTTP Users,CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com,CN=WA Houses,CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com,CN=MTViewMeadows,CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com,CN=ALC0169,CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com,CN=ALC0069,CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com";
memberOf = Replace(memberOf, "CN=Users,DC=alcco,DC=com", "", "all");
memberOf = Replace(memberOf, ",,", ",", "all");
memberOf = Replace(memberOf, "CN=", "", "all");
memberArray =  ListToArray(memberOf);
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
    #memberOf#<br/><br/>
    <cfloop array="#memberArray#" index="i">
        <cfif Left(i, 3) eq "ALC">
            #Right(i, Len(i)-3)#<br/>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: result i'm getting in the loop then how to set result in a list with comma saperater ? Like xyz =(firstvalue, secondvalue,,,,n)

Comment: @TGR - you can use the listAppend function.  Outside of the loop, declare variable <cfset myList = "" />.  Inside the loop do the assignment like <cfset myList = listAppend(myList, Right(i, Len(i)-3)) />

Answer (score 1):

I would use list functions.  Note that you can specify your own delimiter.  From your other post, your cfldap tag returned a query named GroupSearch.

```
<cfset ALCNumbers = "">

 <cfloop list = "GroupSearch.MemberOf" Index = "MemberOfThis">

<cfif ListFirst(MemberOfThis, delimiters = "=") is "CN"
 and left(ListLast MemberOfThis, delimiters = "="), 3) is "ALC">

<cfset ALCNumbers = ListAppend(ALCNUmbers, mid(ListLast MemberOfThis, delimiters = "="), 4,
len(ListLast MemberOfThis, delimiters = "=") - 3)>

</cfif>

</cfloop>
```

This may have syntax errors because I simply typed it into the textarea.  However, it shows the general idea.